# Getting iTunes current track information in C#

Tags: c#, itunes

How do applications like Google Talk and the Last.fm desktop client access iTunes to get the current track that is playing? Is there a library to do this? I am wanting to make an application in C# that posts song information to my website. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATE**

I have some sample code over here to do this in C# using LinqPad
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18246137/215752

---

Here you go : http://developer.apple.com/sdk/itunescomsdk.html

You need to register with apple of course.

---

Here is a link to some example code using C# and this COM API.  There is also a brief "how to":

http://www.ohscope.com/2009/04/itunes-com-api-in-c.html

Comment: Thanks for the info! I swear I searched google for a few hours and came up with nothing.

Comment: Yeah, hard to find.  The key word for google is `COM` as in `iTunes COM API`.  Lots of interesting stuff should come up for you then.