# itunes listening to

Tags: c#, .net, itunes

within windows live messenger, it is possible to share the song you are currently listening to. what would i need to do to get this working within c# like libarys etc cannot find the correct documentation on google.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the `iTunes SDK` to interact with iTunes from .NET. So there's your Google search term. :)

Here's a start:

- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/noahc/archive/2006/07/06/automating-itunes-with-c-in-net.aspx
- http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2004/05/08/128645.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script for LinqPad in C# which does as requested. (see LinqPad.com)

Bonus!  Artwork view.

It looks like this:

[image: example]

```
<Query Kind="Program">
  <Namespace>iTunesLib</Namespace>
  <Namespace>System.Security.Cryptography</Namespace>
</Query>

void Main()
{
  var track = new iTunesApp().CurrentTrack;

  if (track == null)
    "nothing playing".Dump();
  else
    new Viewer(track,true).Dump();
}

public class Viewer
{
  const string PREFIX = "itlps-";

  private IITFileOrCDTrack store;
  private bool materialize;

  public string album { get { return store.Album; } }
  public string band { get { return store.Artist; } }
  public string song { get { return store.Name; } }
  public string desc { get { return store.Description; } }
  public int? artCnt { get {
    if (store.Artwork == null) return null;
    else return store.Artwork.Count; }
  }

  public IEnumerable<ImageViewer> art { get {

    if (materialize)
    {
      foreach(var artT in store.Artwork)
      {
        var art = artT as IITArtwork;
        string ext = ".tmp";
        switch(art.Format)
        {
          case ITArtworkFormat.ITArtworkFormatBMP:
            ext = ".BMP";
            break;
          case ITArtworkFormat.ITArtworkFormatJPEG:
            ext = ".JPG";
            break;
          case ITArtworkFormat.ITArtworkFormatPNG:
            ext = ".PNG";
            break;
        }

        string path = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(),PREFIX+Path.GetRandomFileName()+ext);

        art.SaveArtworkToFile(path);

        yield return new ImageViewer(path);
      }
    }
    yield break; }
  }

  public Viewer(IITFileOrCDTrack t,bool materializeArt = false)
  {
    store = t;
    materialize = materializeArt;
  }

  public Viewer(IITTrack t,bool materializeArt = false)
  {
    store = t as IITFileOrCDTrack;
    materialize = materializeArt;
  }

}

public class ImageViewer
{
  public string hash { get { return _hash.Value; } }
  static private string _path { get; set; }

  public object image { get { return _image.Value; } }

  static private SHA1Managed sha = new SHA1Managed();  

  private Lazy<object> _image = new Lazy<object>(() => {return Util.Image(_path);});
  private Lazy<string> _hash = new Lazy<string>(() =>
  {
    string hash = string.Empty;
    using (FileStream stream = File.OpenRead(_path))
    {
      byte [] checksum = sha.ComputeHash(stream);
      hash = BitConverter.ToString(checksum).Replace("-", string.Empty);
    }  
    return hash;
  });

  public ImageViewer(string path)
  {
    _path = path;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

last i checked this functionality is included out of the box all you need is to have itunes and windows live messenger installed and activate "what im listening to" and it shows this in your messenger status. if you are looking to create a bot that messages this out to a contact that is a different story tho that you will need to write a script for

Comment: I believe he's looking to add it to a custom C# program; not extend the functionality of Windows Live Messenger